# Partial site translations in Umbraco

Tags: localization, umbraco, translation, umbraco7

I'm about to embark down the creation of an Umbraco site, where it will initially be presented in English, but subsequently *some* pages will be presented in foreign languages.

I'm aware the recommendation is to create new root nodes for each language and then create a whole new site for a new language, but in this instance I want to keep 90% of the site in English and have only certain nodes translated, for instance press releases about a certain country.

I've seen [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573563/creating-a-multilingual-site-in-umbraco) on SO but it seems to point to the whole new top node route. Has anyone had any success in just single node translations? I'm not interested in having multiple URLs for multiple languages; just single pages appearing in a different language should that page have a translation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

this package might be your best bet https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/vorto/ basically add the option to add multilingual to any property editor so in theory you can have a page with half English part and half any other language. you get to keep everything under one root, same urls etc but with sections in diff languages.

Comment: That looks like a great option, Denford! I'll install it and give it a go, and report back.